# Select in trigger working incorrectly

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a strange problem with a trigger. I want to insert data into a table named 'profile' and i want the trigger to fill some columns of 'profile' if it is present in another table called 'profile_info'. If it does not exist in 'profile_info' the trigger should add the record's id to 'profile_info' to be filled later.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `info_filler` BEFORE INSERT ON `profile`
 FOR EACH ROW begin

select info1, info2, info3, id from
profile_info where id = new.id into @i1, @i2, @i3, @id;
set new.info1 = @i1;
set new.info2 = @i2;
set new.info3 = @i3;
If @id is null THEN
 insert into profile_info (id) values (new.id);
END IF;
end
```

The trigger worked fine when i added records to 'profile' one by one to check if it works properly. However when many records are added simultaneously (more than 1500 per second), problems started to occur. Some of the records added into profile had wrong info1, info2, info3 columns. For example in 'profile' table i have values like:

```
| id        |  info1     |  info2     |  info3     |
|-----------|------------|------------|------------|
| 1         |     10     |     23     |     12     |
| 2         |     10     |     23     |     12     |
| 3         |     10     |     23     |     12     |
| 4         |     7      |     42     |     73     |
| 5         |     5      |     45     |     33     |
| 6         |     5      |     45     |     33     |
| 7         |     NULL   |     NULL   |     NULL   |
```

My problem is that rows 2, 3, 6 have wrong values for info1, info2 and info3, their values belong to another row. Also these rows are not added to 'profile_info'. 1, 4, 5 and 7 is ok, 7 is also added to 'profile_info'.

I know, i shouldn't be copying same information to another table, i am also working on that. But for now i need this trigger to work and i have no clue what i am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using mysql 5.5 and innodb. Inserts are done by python from multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you change it to:

```
select info1, info2, info3, id from
profile_info where id = new.id into @i1, @i2, @i3, @id;
If @id is null THEN
  insert into profile_info (id) values (new.id);
ELSE
  set new.info1 = @i1;
  set new.info2 = @i2;
  set new.info3 = @i3;
END IF;
```

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. I know i should've written the trigger properly in the first place :)

Comment: I've tried it just like you said, but it didn't help. The records that are showing this error are added at the same second, i think it may be an issue of performance

Comment: what happens if you lock profile at start of the trigger - unlock before you exit?